# Understanding Memory Layout of C Programs

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to understand memory representation of C program but I am having some question as follow:

1. What is code segment and It is a part of which memory (RAM or Flash
   memory)?
2. When are the local and global variables get memory allocated (compile-time or run-time)?

Comment: What do you mean with "'code' memory"?

Comment: This question needs to be reformulated for better quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is 'code' memory and it is a part of which memory (RAM or Flash
>   memory)?

Is one of the sections of a program in an object file or in memory, which contains executable instructions. Code and read-only data are stored in flash memory.

> When are the local and global variables allocated in memory -- during
>   compile-time or run-time?

For Statically allocated local and global variables means that the compiler determines the memory address of the variable at compile time.

Also have look on [RAM/Flash usage](http://coactionos.com/embedded%20design%20tips/2013/10/18/Tips-RAM-Flash-Usage-in-Embedded-C-Programs/).

Comment: What wrong in this answer ...provided link also for proof.

Comment: @amit kr isn't it useful to you???

Comment: Yes the link is very useful,I have gone through it and the ram/flash link given .      Thanks for the answer